# How to draw a Bezier Path passing through touch location if control point is unknown in iPhone?

Tags: bezier, uibezierpath

I have two fixed points, P1 & P2. On touch, How can i draw a Bezier Path passing through P1, Touch point and P2?
In other words, Is there any way to find out the location of control point if we know the touch point location?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want Schneider's bezier curve-fitting algorithm. It takes a bunch of points and fits a bezier curve through them.

http://iut-arles.univ-provence.fr/web/romain-raffin/sites/romain-raffin/IMG/pdf/PSchndeider_An_Algorithm_for_automatically_fitting_digitized_curves.pdf